# Does blackberry browserfield show hindi text?

Tags: blackberry

How to show hindi text in blackberry browserfield ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you installed Hindi support on the device via BB Desktop Software. Then here is the code:

```
        StringBuffer details = new StringBuffer();
        // download HTML to details [...]
        _browserField.displayContent(details.toString().getBytes("utf-8"),
                    "text/html; charset=utf-8", "http://localhost");
```